# Вывод названия таксономии WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. В нём присутствует таксономия `location`. Хочу вывести на каждой записи название категорий этой таксономии. Использую код:

```
$countlocs = 1;
$cats = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'location' );
if(!empty($cats)){
echo '<span class="cat-icon">'.listingpro_icons('mapMarkerGrey').'</span>';
foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
if($countlocs==1){
$term_link = get_term_link( $cat );
echo '<a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$cat->name.'</a>';
}
$countlocs ++;
}
}
```

Но если запись имеет две и более категории из этой таксономии, то выводиться все ровно только одна. Подскажите, в чём может быть дело?

Дополняю вопрос. Получилось вывести все категории при помощи удаления `countlocs` . Код получился такой:

```
$cats = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'location' );
if(!empty($cats)){
echo '<span class="cat-icon">'.listingpro_icons('mapMarkerGrey').'</span>';
foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
$term_link = get_term_link( $cat );
echo '<a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$cat->name.'</a>';
}
}
```

Но хотелось бы разделить категории запятыми. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уберите `if($countlocs==1)`

Он тут совершенно не нужен.

Код к дополненному вопросу

```
$cats = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'location' );
if ( ! empty( $cats ) ) {
    echo '<span class="cat-icon">' . listingpro_icons( 'mapMarkerGrey' ) . '</span>';
    foreach ( $cats as $key => $cat ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $cat );
        echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $cat->name . '</a>';
        if ( count( $cats ) !== ( $key + 1 ) ) {
            echo ', ';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось. Я дополнил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста. Может сможете помочь. Я хотел бы разделить категории запятыми

Comment: Спасибо, но получается, что после последней категории тоже стоит запятая. Можно было просто сделать так: '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $cat->name . '</a> , ' но в конце тоже есть запятая

Comment: Поправил ответ..

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает!